# Convert System.Drawing.Bitmap to stdole.StdPicture

Tags: c#, interop, compatibility, ole

I have a System.Drawing.Bitmap currently and I need to convert it into an stdole.StdPicture.
Currently I'm using:

```
var pic = (stdole.StdPicture)Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility.VB6.Support.ImageToIPicture
                   (MyDLL.Properties.Resources.Img); // this is a System.Drawing.Bitmap
```

but I get a Compiler Warning:

> Warning 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility.VB6.Support.ImageToIPicture(System.Drawing.Image)' is obsolete: '"Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility.* classes are obsolete and supported within 32 bit processes only. http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=160862

So what to use instead? I couldn't find another solution yet...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

taken from NetOffice http://netoffice.codeplex.com Office Addin Example

```
public class IconConverter : System.Windows.Forms.AxHost
{
   private IconConverter(): base(string.Empty)
   {
   }

   public static stdole.IPictureDisp GetIPictureDispFromImage(System.Drawing.Image image)
   {

      return (stdole.IPictureDisp)GetIPictureDispFromPicture(image);
   }
}
```

Comment: You find more details in the original post where the above has been copied from: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/andreww/2007/07/30/converting-between-ipicturedisp-and-system-drawing-image

Comment: For those who are wondering what is "stdole": You find it in Visual Studio Solution Explorer -> Refecence -> Add Reference -> .NET -> stdole

Answer (score 0):

If you do a Google search for [convert .net image to ole picture], you'll find a whole lot of chatter about going the other way (i.e. converting an ole picture to image), and a lot of advice that says, in effect, "don't try to use ole pictures in .NET". I concur. I went down that path a few years ago and decided that I didn't really need the OLE picture that badly.

I strongly recommend that you re-evaluate your need for OLE picture objects. If you're saving images in a database, store them as BLOBs rather than as picture objects. If you absolutely have to use OLE picture objects, then good luck. It's going to be very frustrating.

Comment: It seems a lot of people need to do this in the callback of loadImage to customize ribbon button images. The signature of the callback is `Public Function OnLoadImage(imageId As String) As IPictureDisp` Do you have a suggestion on how to solve that?