# Load a Bitmap into VB 6 PictureBox

Tags: vb6

I wrote a library which has a function call that returns a System.Drawing.Bitmap. Everything works great and I can access it just fine from a C# WPF application. However, now I need to make it work with a VB 6 application and for the life of me I can`t get it to work. I have a VB6 picturebox (note: this could be changed to an image control if necessary; we just need the image to display on the screen somehow) Right now I have tried the following unsuccessfully:

```
Set Form1.PictureBox1.Image = myImage <-- This causes invalid use of property on 'Form1.PictureBox1.Image'

Form1.PictureBox1.Image = myImage <-- This causes invalid use of property on 'Form1.PictureBox1.Image'

Form1.PictureBox1.Picture = myImage <-- This cause 'type mismatch'
```

Help please! I don`t know VB at all let alone VB 6.

Comment: Add the Set keyword to your first example and it should work, barring any issues with what's in myImage.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but that doesn`t work (edited the question to reflect that). Any other control ideas? I`m not tied to a picture box.

Comment: This is just a thought... but VB6 probably doesn't use the System.Drawing.Bitmap for PictureBox, since that framework did not even exist when VB6 was designed. You may have to do an intermediary step, like have another method in your library that saves the image to disk, and then have the VB6 application load from disk.

Comment: Ok, if adding Set didn't work, you'll need to compare what you've got in myImage to the data expected by the .Image property as vbnet3d suggested.

Comment: Ok, thanks guys I may just have to pass the original byte array that composes the picture and then draw it that way (with PSet I believe)

Comment: You might also look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6110337/convert-system-drawing-bitmap-to-stdole-stdpicture  --- if you can simply convert it in your library, that will make your VB6 application more seamless.